# Can Solana Accounts be accessed by any Solana Program using its address?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account, security, account-data

If I have a deployed Solana Program which creates some Solana accounts for storing data in it. **Can these Solana accounts be accessed by any other Solana program using the account addresses?** I am confused about the security features for the data stored in the account since accounts are mutable and if any other program can access it then there's a risk of data getting changed right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Reading

Any program can *read* data from and *credit* SOL to any Solana account.

## Writing

Where permission to *write* to an account is concerned, there are restrictions. All Solana accounts have a field of metadata on them named `owner`. In that field you will find the address of a *program*. The Solana runtime will only grant a program write access to an account if the program's address matches the address stored in the `owner` field of the account being written to.

## Example

By default, newly created accounts are owned by the System Program[1]. Writes to these accounts are thereby *mediated* by the System Program. As an example: let's say that you wanted to *debit* an account (ie. transfer some SOL tokens *out* of it). Since the System Program is the only program that can perform such a mutation, you will have to convince it to do so on your behalf. The canonical way to do this is to call its `Transfer` instruction. In order for that instruction to succeed, the System Program will require that you produce a cryptographic signature as proof that you *own* the account being debited.

---

*[1] The address of the System Program is `11111111111111111111111111111111`*.

Comment: What about accessing a user deployed solana program? Who can access that?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘accessing,’ @RounakNaik? If your question is ‘who can execute a user deployed Solana program,’ executing is a kind of reading; you can execute any program that you can read (which is all of them).

Comment: by 'accessing' I mean who can write data or change data stored in Solana accounts?

Comment: Read about the [upgrade authority](https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#set-a-programs-upgrade-authority) and [immutabillity](https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#immutable-programs).